# jQuery UI : Select menu does not close when clicking inside div of swiper plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu, swiper.js

I have a maybe little problem. I use the swiper plugin and inside I have one select that is overrided by the jQuery UI select menu.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(select).selectmenu()

var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    paginationClickable: true,
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    spaceBetween: 0
});
</script>


<div class="swiper-container responsive">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper" style="background:red;">
    <!--First Slide-->
    <div class="swiper-slide ">
        page1
        <select>
            <option>test1</option>
            <option>test2</option>
            <option>test3</option>
        </select>
    </div>

      <!--Second Slide-->
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        page2
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem is the following:

When i click on the selectmenu it opens correctly, but when i then click inside the swiper div instead chosing an option the selectmenu does not close - only in internet explorer 11 here :/. It stays open which is pretty shit, when it goes to the second slide.

I use the latest jQuery UI and swiper version.

I have no clue what could be going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. Adding following code in the swiper.js does the trick for me:

Inside functions s.onTouchStart and s.updateClickedSlide

```
$('select').selectmenu('close');
```

Not pretty, but works!